# An adjective similar to ominous

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

In education, teachers may use the term "the district" when referring to the school district. It often has a negative connotation.

An example may be: "I heard 'the district' is going to cut all of our benefits to save money." I am looking for a word that I could use in a sentence such as:

> "Other generations of teachers are left feeling they do not have a
>   voice, their 'people focus' is not valued by the _________ district."

*Ominous* does not seem quite right. It would be a word meaning dark, presumed to intend harm, faceless, cold, and uncaring.

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: There is such a thing as a "thesaurus".  Several are available online for free.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of words suggesting that you think the district is being excessively cautious in spending:

- *tight-fisted*
- *stingy*
- *stinting*
- *miserly*
- *niggardly* (careful)

If you wish to suggest that the district is being deliberately evil, look up synonyms for *malicious*.

Answer (score -1):

How about "indifferent" or "oblivious", neither of which has the dark element you are looking for, but may actually reflect the district's true perspective on these teachers?

Or, at the other end of the darkness scale, how about "nefarious", implying intentional evil, or "malevolent" or "malicious", implying intentional harm?

In between, how about "predatory" or "disdainful"?